# Cannot access remote jupyter instance via browser when running it as a user service through systemd

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a jupyter instance running on a remote server in aws.

When I try to access it from my local computer via the browser I always get the following:
[image]

I've tried multiple different browsers and it's the same thing.

But it get's even stranger, if I fire up a terminal and just ssh into the remote aws server, nothing else, now all of a sudden I can access the jupyter instance from my local computer via the browser by just visiting the url of the notebook.

[image]

Any idea what the heck is going on here?

Here's a more detailed description. We have two machines **A** (**local**) and **B** (**remote**). On machine **B** jupyter-lab is installed using conda.

In order to access jupyter-lab from my local machine **A** I simply start jupyter-lab on machine **B** on port **80** and then all I have to do is to visit the url *public ip/domain name* of machine **B** in the browser of machine **A**.

No need for ssh tunneling cause machine **B** has a public ip and a domain name associated with it, e.g. *machineB.aws.com:80* points to the jupyter-lab instance running on machine **B**.

Now the bizarre thing in all this is that visiting the url machineB.aws.com:80 from the browser in machine **A** always gives the error "*The site can't be reached*", unless I simply ssh from machine **A** into machine **B**, then the site is reachable and the url **machineB.aws.com:80** works fine.

Again, no ssh tunneling going on here, simply ssh from **A** --> **B** makes the site reachable?

**Clarification**

This issue is being caused by the fact that I have configured jupyter-lab to run as user service via systemd. According to the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances) `This process will survive as long as there is some session for that user, and will be killed as soon as the last session for the user is closed. When #Automatic start-up of systemd user instances is enabled, the instance is started on boot and will not be killed.` If I'm not mistaken I have configured the user service to start-up automatically upon each boot of the computer. Which makes me a bit skeptical why process is being killed when no user is logged in?

Here's the systemd unit file configuration for jupyter:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyter Lab

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/jupyter-lab
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/
Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: You don't share much information about how you set this up or what tutorials you followed in your attempt and so advising you is difficult. However, my first guess based on it working when you ssh into the terminal is that you are failing in **your normal attempts** to make the ssh tunnel from your local computer to the remote machine. Hopefully what you followed told you that once you have Jupyter notebook running on the remote machine you need to forward what is the localhost on the remote machine to localhost on your local machine so you see it in your local browser.

Comment: Thanks. I've added more context. There's no ssh tunneling going on in this case, at least not directly in case. If I understand correctly you're referring to a different type of tunneling though, from A to B when I visit the url in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, I think there is need to tunnel. I suspect it doesn't work the way you claim. It's not a JupyterHub. I think it used to work the way you think but it wasn't secure enough and so other stuff is in play. Whatever the reason if you add in the SSH tunnel, then it will work as you found. The connection you have is acting like part of a tunnel because it open, it seems? Most current directions of using AWS online cover the tunneling and so that is why I was asking to reference your source.

Comment: I'm not sure this has to do with tunneling. I believe this has to do with the user session on machine B. I found that If I open a tmux session on machine B and close the ssh connection to machine B, but without terminating the tmux session (this is just an empty tmux session), then I can reach jupyter-lab fine via the url in machine A.

Comment: So security is set to use without tunnel but you were you closing the terminal/processes on the remote machine before? I'm getting confused now with what is working or not.  (And what you added in the following quote makes it sound like it does work: "In order to access jupyter-lab from my local machine A I simply start jupyter-lab on machine B on port 80 and then all I have to do is to visit the url public ip/domain name of machine B in the browser of machine A."  But it doesn't work right?)

Comment: Hi Wayne, I figure out what is going on. I have updated the post to clarify what I found out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I might have forgotten to issue the following command:
`loginctl enable-linger username`, which is necessary for a systemd user process to run without a user session on startup and to keep running even after a user session has been closed. This is mentioned in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances:%7E:text=for%20configuration%20details.-,Automatic%20start%2Dup%20of%20systemd%20user%20instances,-The%20systemd%20user) and also mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1025091/start-a-systemd-user-service-at-boot), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555383/systemd-per-user-instance-does-not-start-a-service-unit-automatically) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot)